# VBA How to check for duplicate values against existing list and add only unique instances from new list

Tags: excel, vba, loops, dictionary, duplicates

I have three worksheets with consistent headers, but the # of columns vary:

1. Active List
2. Current List
3. New List

I need to compare column A from "New List" against Column B from "Active List" for duplicate instances.
I want to load only the unique instances from column A starting at row 2 along with the associated cells in Column B on my "New List" beneath the last, populated row of my "Active List" worksheet in columns B & C.

To do this, I have tried utilizing the Scripting Dictionary, but I receive Run Time Error 1004 on my object range in the following line of code:

```
Dict.Add Key:=NL.Range(i, "A").Value, Item:=vbNullString
```

Here is the full code which I mimicked from question [#55499372](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55499372/how-do-i-append-items-from-list-b-to-list-a-that-are-in-list-b-but-not-in-list) on StackOverflow:

```
Sub load_new()

 Dim LastRow As Long
 Dim i As Long
 
 Dim Dict As Scripting.Dictionary
 Set Dict = New Scripting.Dictionary
 Dim CL As Worksheet
 Set CL = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CURRENT LIST")
 Dim NL As Worksheet
 Set NL = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("NEW LIST")
 Dim AL As Worksheet
 Set AL = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ACTIVE LIST")

    'Retrieves the last row of column A
    With NL
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
 
    For i = 2 To LastRow
        Dict.Add Key:=NL.Range(i, 1).Value, Item:=vbNullString
    Next i
    

    'Retrieves the last row of column B
    With AL
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    For i = 2 To LastRow
        If Not Dict.Exists(AL.Range(i, 2).Value) Then
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: `NL.Range(i, 1).Value` should be `NL.Cells(i, 1).Value`

Comment: Thank you! The sub runs free and clear now without errors! Unfortunately, I still don't see the unique values from the new list added beneath the last populated row of my "Active" list - any additional suggestions? I have the feeling I am missing something.

Comment: The code you posted in the question does not have anything that writes the value into the worksheet if `Not Dict.Exists(AL.Cells(i,2).Value)` is true, so what did you tried? Note: Similar to what CDP1802 advised you earlier, `AL.Range(i,2).Value` should be `AL.Cells(i,2).Value`

Comment: By unique do you mean values in col A of new sheet that don't appear in col B of active list ? If so create the dict from the active sheet and check exists by scanning the new list. Use different lastrow variables so you can use the active list one to add the new records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load the dictionary with keys from Active List column B, then scan the New List column A checking if key does not exist.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub load_new()

    Dim wsCL As Worksheet, wsNL As Worksheet, wsAL As Worksheet
    Dim LastRowAL As Long, LastRowNL As Long
    Dim i As Long, n As Long, key As String
    
    Dim Dict As Scripting.dictionary
    Set Dict = New Scripting.dictionary
    With ThisWorkbook
        'Set wsCL = .Sheets("CURRENT LIST")
        Set wsNL = .Sheets("NEW LIST")
        Set wsAL = .Sheets("ACTIVE LIST")
    End With

    ' Active List
    With wsAL
        LastRowAL = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To LastRowAL
            key = Trim(.Cells(i, "B"))
            If Len(key) > 0 Then
                Dict.Add key, i
            End If
        Next i
    End With
 
    ' New List
    With wsNL
        LastRowNL = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To LastRowNL
            key = Trim(.Cells(i, "A"))
            If Not Dict.Exists(key) Then
                LastRowAL = LastRowAL + 1
                wsAL.Cells(LastRowAL, "B") = key
                wsAL.Cells(LastRowAL, "C") = .Cells(i, "B")
               n = n + 1
            End If
        Next i
    End With
    MsgBox n & " rows added to " & wsAL.Name

End Sub
```

Comment: This worked like a charm! Thank you very much, @CDP1802!